# How to assign value to gridview

Tags: c#, gridview

i have some question? if i want to assign value to column in gridview and that column not have DataField .it's possible to do that.Because in my data table doesn't have the column in gridview .For example

My DataTable have 6 column {id, code, description, price1, price2, price3}
and this my gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridview" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" OnRowCancelingEdit="gridview_RowCancelingEdit1" OnRowEditing="gridview_RowEditing1" OnRowUpdating="gridview_RowUpdating">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowEditButton="True" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-primary" HeaderStyle-Width="80" >
                                <ControlStyle CssClass="btn btn-primary"></ControlStyle>
                                <HeaderStyle Width="80px"></HeaderStyle>
                            </asp:CommandField>

                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ITM_RowId" HeaderText="No." ReadOnly="true" HeaderStyle-Width="80" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ITM_Code" HeaderText="ItemCode" HeaderStyle-Width="80" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ITM_Desc" HeaderStyle-Width="80" HeaderText="Item Descrition" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="OPD_Price" HeaderStyle-Width="80" HeaderText="Existing OPD Price" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="IPD_Price" HeaderStyle-Width="80" HeaderText="Existing IPD Price" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Tou_Price" HeaderStyle-Width="80" HeaderText="Existing Tourist Price" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="New OPD Price" HeaderStyle-Width="80" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="New IPD Price" HeaderStyle-Width="80" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="New Tourist Price" HeaderStyle-Width="80" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-Width="80" HeaderText="Margin OPD Price" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-Width="80" HeaderText="Margin IPD Price" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-Width="80" HeaderText="Margin Tourist Price" />     
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdf" runat="server" />
```

in is case column{ ITM_RowId, ITM_Code, ITM_Desc, OPD_Price(price1), IPD_Price(price2), Tou_Price(price3)} is no problem but if i want to assign value to column{ Margin OPD Price, Margin IPD Price", Margin Tourist Price} it's possible ?

Comment: `assign value` means `bind value`?

Comment: Looking at your GridView, you are not binding values for few columns which you have mentioned. So if you want to calculate values for those columns for each row, then you need to use `RowDataBound` event of the GridView

Comment: i want to calculate value and assing it when user click button update with commond boundField

Comment: Then you need to write your code in `gridview_RowUpdating` event.

Comment: code calculate is not problem. but i don't know how to assign data from calculate to column{ Margin OPD Price, Margin IPD Price", Margin Tourist Price}

Comment: Ahh, then do one thing, change those columns to `<asp:TemplateField/>` and use `<asp:Label/>` in it. You get a row on update button click, then find those Labels and assign result to `Text` property. Like, `((Label)row.FindControl("label_id")).Text = calculated_result;`.

Comment: OK. Thank you for reply.if it not work i will comment it agian ,thank u a lot.